# Nuget scaffolding installation failure

Tags: nuget, scaffolding, mvcmailer

I am trying to install scaffolding package in VS2010 SP1 in MVC4(aim is to user MvcMailer), here are the command I run

```
PM> install-package T4Scaffolding
PM> install-package MvcScaffolding
```

and installing T4Scaffolding gives me this error:

> Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///path/packages\T4Scaffolding.1.0.5\tools\T4Scaffolding.dll' or
>   one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from 
>   HRESULT: 0x80131515)

if I use installed it again, it installed but when I use Scaffolding command gives me this error

```
PM> Scaffolding Mailer.Razor UserMailer subs
```

> The term 'Scaffolding' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again. At line:1 char:12
>   + Scaffolding <<<<  Mailer.Razor UserMailer subs
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Scaffolding:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I tried uninstalling and deleting the packages and re installing but no luck.  I tried update command on both packages but nothing.

When I run import-module "dllpath"

I get same error message i.e.

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///path/packages\T4Scaffolding.1.0.5\tools\T4Scaffolding.dll' or
>   one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from 
>   HRESULT: 0x80131515)

Tried restarting VS after uninstall, install, reinstall all possible but nothing changed.

What I am doing wrong.

EDIT: I have tried to use power shell

> PS C:\Windows\system32> import-module
>   "path\T4Scaffolding.1.0.5\tools\T4Scaffolding.dll" Import-Module :
>   Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///path\T4Scaffolding.1.0.5\tools\T4Scaffolding.d ll' or one of
>   its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the
>   currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded. At line:1 char:14
>   + import-module <<<<  "path\T4Scaffolding.1.0.5\tools\T4Scaffolding.dll"
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], BadImageFormatException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
>   System.BadImageFormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

It gives error "This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot
be loaded." I believe here is the start failing point. Any idea? how to fix this first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, nothing new in solution but had to do a lot of search, hit and trial, I had VS2010 SP1, default installation. Project was loaded from network drive.

Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///path/packages\T4Scaffolding.1.0.5\tools\T4Scaffolding.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported.

Above error message comes from VS, because it can't load things from remote source. 
Fix: Go to your Visual Studio devenv.exe location. i.e. default C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
in devenv.exe.config add line in  runtime section i.e.  :

```
<configuration>
<configSections>

</configSections>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
    <requiredRuntime version="v4.0.30319" safemode="true"/>

</startup>
<runtime>
<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
```

I wish error message was more proper at first place but I should also read more.